# Two Brownian motions and stopping time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

X and Y are two independent Brownian motions both equal to $1$ at time $0$. Consider the first time, T, that Y process hits $0$. What is the probability that $X_T>0$?

My intuition: I think that at any time $t>0$, $P(X_t>Y_t)=0.5$. The question asks about the random time T and at T we know $Y_T=0$. So $P(X_T>0) = P(X_T>Y_T) = 0.5$.

I would like to know if my intuition is correct? I appreciate it if anyone can provide a hint for a more formal solution. Thanks, guys!

Comment: Your intuition does not work because $T$ is a random variable, and it is not independent of $Y$.

Comment: running a sim, the probability is consistently less than 0.5

Comment: @MikeEarnest: I see. So, the intuition fails because T is not independent of Y.

Comment: @phdmba7of12: Wow, running a simul to check the intuition is a brilliant idea. I guess you meant "larger than 0.5".

Comment: correct ... greater than 0.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $S$ be the first time that $X$ hits $0$.

- If $S>T$, then certainly $X_T>0$.
- If $S<T$, then $Z_r:= X_{S+r}$ is a Brownian motion independent of $Y$ with $Z_0=0$, so $P(Z_{T-S}>0\mid S<T)=\frac12$.

Furthermore, $P(T>S)=\frac12$.

Comment: but that isn't what the question is asking ... it's asking $P(X_T>0)$

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for the hint! So, P(X(T)>0) = P(S>T)+P(S<T)*P(Z_{T-S}>0)=1/2+1/2*1/2=3/4.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Perhaps it takes a little more work to make these arguments rigorous, but I think you now have a good road map to find a rigorous proof. @XinWei